# How to get steam items names?

Tags: steam, steam-web-api, steambot

I am trying to find the name of the item on steam.

This is what i get currently from json array

```
[appid] => 730
[contextid] => 2
[assetid] => 4981322842
[classid] => 311848115
[instanceid] => 188530139
```

How can I "convert" this to the item name or market hash name ?

If i add get_descriptions=1 to my request I get item description with names inside json array .

Now I am not really sure how to get prices from here.

Comment: Just FYI, the code paste is no longer available. In the interests of improving the quality of this question for subsequent readers, would you consider incorporating the code right here on SO?

Answer (score 1):

I think this one is same as your next question.

with this code, You will get, instanceid, classid, assetid, amount, market_hash_name, market_name, name, etc. You can learn to edit the response result.

```
{
    "items_to_give": [
        {
            "instanceid": "480085569",
            "classid": "1440311074",
            "assetid": "5003822520",
            "amount": "1",
            "market_hash_name": "AWP | Asiimov (Field-Tested)",
            "market_name": "AWP | Asiimov (Field-Tested)",
            "name": "AWP | Asiimov",
            "icon_url": "-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpot621FAR17PLfYQJD_9W7m5a0mvLwOq7c2G9SupUijOjAotyg3w2x_0ZkZ2rzd4OXdgRoYQuE8gDtyL_mg5K4tJ7XiSw0WqKv8kM",
            "action_link": "steam:\/\/rungame\/730\/76561202255233023\/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20S%owner_steamid%A%assetid%D9394689721994738281"
        },
        {
            "instanceid": "188530139",
            "classid": "310777979",
            "assetid": "4999225449",
            "amount": "1",
            "market_hash_name": "M4A4 | Asiimov (Field-Tested)",
            "market_name": "M4A4 | Asiimov (Field-Tested)",
            "name": "M4A4 | Asiimov",
            "icon_url": "-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpou-6kejhjxszFJQJD_9W7m5a0mvLwOq7c2GlUucFwjruR9t7231DmrRc_NW7yItCRcVNoYVHS-APrwbzu0JK-78nXiSw0EnwDRM0",
            "action_link": "steam:\/\/rungame\/730\/76561202255233023\/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20S%owner_steamid%A%assetid%D459488816407887944"
        }
    ],
    "items_to_receive": [
        {
            "instanceid": "188530139",
            "classid": "1015898744",
            "assetid": "5004700589",
            "amount": "1",
            "market_hash_name": "\u2605 Falchion Knife | Blue Steel (Field-Tested)",
            "market_name": "\u2605 Falchion Knife | Blue Steel (Field-Tested)",
            "name": "\u2605 Falchion Knife | Blue Steel",
            "icon_url": "-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpovbSsLQJf1fLEcjVL49KJlZG0lfvhNr_um25V4dB8xOrApdqmjAbi_hFtYGr7cICUdVVtNA6D81m9yObr0cDotJnJnSM3viU8pSGKmL5fGRg",
            "action_link": "steam:\/\/rungame\/730\/76561202255233023\/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20S%owner_steamid%A%assetid%D14288283571522546212"
        }
    ]
}
```

---

**This is the code:**

```
<?php
$steamResponse = '{
    "response": {
        "trade_offers_received": [
            {
                "tradeofferid": "993371789",
                "accountid_other": 254083372,
                "message": "I just got a fantastic idea. This could make everything good between us.          ;)",
                "expiration_time": 1455660736,
                "trade_offer_state": 7,
                "items_to_give": [
                    {
                        "appid": "730",
                        "contextid": "2",
                        "assetid": "5003822520",
                        "classid": "1440311074",
                        "instanceid": "480085569",
                        "amount": "1",
                        "missing": false
                    },
                    {
                        "appid": "730",
                        "contextid": "2",
                        "assetid": "4999225449",
                        "classid": "310777979",
                        "instanceid": "188530139",
                        "amount": "1",
                        "missing": false
                    }
                ]
                ,
                "items_to_receive": [
                    {
                        "appid": "730",
                        "contextid": "2",
                        "assetid": "5004700589",
                        "classid": "1015898744",
                        "instanceid": "188530139",
                        "amount": "1",
                        "missing": false
                    }
                ]
                ,
                "is_our_offer": false,
                "time_created": 1454451136,
                "time_updated": 1454451250,
                "from_real_time_trade": false,
                "escrow_end_date": 0,
                "confirmation_method": 0
            }
        ]
        ,
        "descriptions": [
            {
                "appid": 730,
                "classid": "1440311074",
                "instanceid": "480085569",
                "currency": false,
                "background_color": "",
                "icon_url": "-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpot621FAR17PLfYQJD_9W7m5a0mvLwOq7c2G9SupUijOjAotyg3w2x_0ZkZ2rzd4OXdgRoYQuE8gDtyL_mg5K4tJ7XiSw0WqKv8kM",
                "icon_url_large": "-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpot621FAR17PLfYQJD_9W7m5a0mvLwOq7cqWdQ-sJ0xOzAot-jiQa3-hBqYzvzLdSVJlQ3NQvR-FfsxL3qh5e7vM6bzSA26Sg8pSGKJUPeNtY",
                "descriptions": [
                    {
                        "type": "html",
                        "value": "Exterior: Field-Tested"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "html",
                        "value": " "
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "html",
                        "value": "High risk and high reward, the infamous AWP is recognizable by its signature report and one-shot, one-kill policy. It has been custom painted with a sci-fi design.\n\n<i>Anyone can predict the future... a visionary shapes it</i>"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "html",
                        "value": " "
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "html",
                        "value": "The Phoenix Collection",
                        "color": "9da1a9"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "html",
                        "value": " "
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "html",
                        "value": "<br><div id=\"sticker_info\" name=\"sticker_info\" title=\"Sticker Details\" style=\"border: 2px solid rgb(102, 102, 102); border-radius: 6px; width=100; margin:4px; padding:8px;\"><center><img width=64 height=48 src=\"https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/apps/730/icons/econ/stickers/team_roles_capsule/baiter.f14ba197e75a0b0074c74e7f98af9eb4d111981b.png\"><img width=64 height=48 src=\"https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/apps/730/icons/econ/stickers/team_roles_capsule/lurker.850f26af6a1e55f4ed398da610d9ceb73ce0b338.png\"><img width=64 height=48 src=\"https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/apps/730/icons/econ/stickers/team_roles_capsule/awper.251e754fcfd1d398fcedc220dc44f479b841c8ea.png\"><br>Sticker: The Baiter, The Lurker, The Awper</center></div>"
                    }
                ]
                ,
                "tradable": true,
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "link": "steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20S%owner_steamid%A%assetid%D9394689721994738281",
                        "name": "Inspect in Game..."
                    }
                ]
                ,
                "name": "AWP | Asiimov",
                "name_color": "D2D2D2",
                "type": "Covert Sniper Rifle",
                "market_name": "AWP | Asiimov (Field-Tested)",
                "market_hash_name": "AWP | Asiimov (Field-Tested)",
                "market_actions": [
                    {
                        "link": "steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20M%listingid%A%assetid%D9394689721994738281",
                        "name": "Inspect in Game..."
                    }
                ]
                ,
                "commodity": false,
                "market_tradable_restriction": 7
            },
            {
                "appid": 730,
                "classid": "310777979",
                "instanceid": "188530139",
                "currency": false,
                "background_color": "",
                "icon_url": "-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpou-6kejhjxszFJQJD_9W7m5a0mvLwOq7c2GlUucFwjruR9t7231DmrRc_NW7yItCRcVNoYVHS-APrwbzu0JK-78nXiSw0EnwDRM0",
                "icon_url_large": "-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpou-6kejhjxszFJQJD_9W7m5a0mvLwOq7cqWdQ-sJ0xOvEpIj0jAbkqEE_ZD3xctLGJAE_Zw7U-QTowefth8TpvM_InHZh6XQ8pSGKWYJAoJI",
                "descriptions": [
                    {
                        "type": "html",
                        "value": "Exterior: Field-Tested"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "html",
                        "value": " "
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "html",
                        "value": "More accurate but less damaging than its AK-47 counterpart, the M4A4 is the full-auto assault rifle of choice for CTs. It has been custom painted with a sci-fi design.\n\n<i>Anyone can predict the future... a visionary shapes it</i>"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "html",
                        "value": " "
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "html",
                        "value": "The Winter Offensive Collection",
                        "color": "9da1a9"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "html",
                        "value": " "
                    }
                ]
                ,
                "tradable": true,
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "link": "steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20S%owner_steamid%A%assetid%D459488816407887944",
                        "name": "Inspect in Game..."
                    }
                ]
                ,
                "name": "M4A4 | Asiimov",
                "name_color": "D2D2D2",
                "type": "Covert Rifle",
                "market_name": "M4A4 | Asiimov (Field-Tested)",
                "market_hash_name": "M4A4 | Asiimov (Field-Tested)",
                "market_actions": [
                    {
                        "link": "steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20M%listingid%A%assetid%D459488816407887944",
                        "name": "Inspect in Game..."
                    }
                ]
                ,
                "commodity": false,
                "market_tradable_restriction": 7
            },
            {
                "appid": 730,
                "classid": "1015898744",
                "instanceid": "188530139",
                "currency": false,
                "background_color": "",
                "icon_url": "-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpovbSsLQJf1fLEcjVL49KJlZG0lfvhNr_um25V4dB8xOrApdqmjAbi_hFtYGr7cICUdVVtNA6D81m9yObr0cDotJnJnSM3viU8pSGKmL5fGRg",
                "icon_url_large": "-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpovbSsLQJf1fLEcjVL49KJlZG0lfvhNr_um25V4dB8teXA54vwxle1-0VvN2v1IdSUcQU2NV7R_QLtlLi8jJ6_tZXNnSQ3siQisS6JmxCpwUYbIOval6A",
                "descriptions": [
                    {
                        "type": "html",
                        "value": "Exterior: Field-Tested"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "html",
                        "value": " "
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "html",
                        "value": "A modern homage to a falchion sword, this clip point blade has a curved edge. It has been cold blued.\n\n<i>This is the malbec of weapon design - Booth, Arms Dealer</i>"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "html",
                        "value": " "
                    }
                ]
                ,
                "tradable": true,
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "link": "steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20S%owner_steamid%A%assetid%D14288283571522546212",
                        "name": "Inspect in Game..."
                    }
                ]
                ,
                "name": "★ Falchion Knife | Blue Steel",
                "name_color": "8650AC",
                "type": "★ Covert Knife",
                "market_name": "★ Falchion Knife | Blue Steel (Field-Tested)",
                "market_hash_name": "★ Falchion Knife | Blue Steel (Field-Tested)",
                "market_actions": [
                    {
                        "link": "steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20M%listingid%A%assetid%D14288283571522546212",
                        "name": "Inspect in Game..."
                    }
                ]
                ,
                "commodity": false,
                "market_tradable_restriction": 7
            }
        ]

    }
}';


$json = json_decode($steamResponse); // $steamResponse is the json response from steam

$result = array();
$result['items_to_give'] = array();
$result['items_to_receive'] = array();


foreach($json->response->trade_offers_received[0]->items_to_give as $key => $value){
    $result['items_to_give'][$key]['instanceid'] = $value->instanceid;
    $result['items_to_give'][$key]['classid'] = $value->classid;
    $result['items_to_give'][$key]['assetid'] = $value->assetid;
    $result['items_to_give'][$key]['amount'] = $value->amount;

    foreach($json->response->descriptions as $key2 => $value2){
        if(($value2->instanceid == $value->instanceid) && ($value2->classid == $value->classid)){
            $result['items_to_give'][$key]['market_hash_name'] = $value2->market_hash_name;
            $result['items_to_give'][$key]['market_name'] = $value2->market_name;
            $result['items_to_give'][$key]['name'] = $value2->name;
            $result['items_to_give'][$key]['icon_url'] = $value2->icon_url;
            $result['items_to_give'][$key]['action_link'] = $value2->actions[0]->link;
        }
    }
}

foreach($json->response->trade_offers_received[0]->items_to_receive as $key => $value){
    $result['items_to_receive'][$key]['instanceid'] = $value->instanceid;
    $result['items_to_receive'][$key]['classid'] = $value->classid;
    $result['items_to_receive'][$key]['assetid'] = $value->assetid;
    $result['items_to_receive'][$key]['amount'] = $value->amount;
    foreach($json->response->descriptions as $key2 => $value2){
        if(($value2->instanceid == $value->instanceid) && ($value2->classid == $value->classid)){
            $result['items_to_receive'][$key]['market_hash_name'] = $value2->market_hash_name;
            $result['items_to_receive'][$key]['market_name'] = $value2->market_name;
            $result['items_to_receive'][$key]['name'] = $value2->name;
            $result['items_to_receive'][$key]['icon_url'] = $value2->icon_url;
            $result['items_to_receive'][$key]['action_link'] = $value2->actions[0]->link;
        }
    }
}


echo '<pre>';
print_r(json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
echo '</pre>';
```